# Why is jQuery running in my console but not in my script

Tags: jquery, console

Basically as the title says... this code will run in the console but not in the actual script and I have no idea why...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $(".twitter-timeline").contents().find(".timeline-header h1.summary").css("display","none");
    }, 1000);
});
```

anyone able to shed any light on this? thanks

Comment: Is this `$(".twitter-timeline")` a iFrame? btw, i don't whink you need `window` there...

Comment: are you sure 1 second is long enough? try 30 seconds. (or preferably find another way of doing it that doesn't involve a setTimeout)

Comment: try without the window

Comment: @Sergio and Melc thank you, removed the window and it worked

Comment: Please show us the HTML that you're searching.

Comment: If you think that changing `window.setTimeout()` to just `setTimeout()` actually fixed anything, good luck with that.  You are apparently getting lucky with some sort of timing now and your code may just as well stop working tomorrow.  You didn't actually fix anything - you're just getting luck now with the timing.

Comment: lol... brilliant, thanks for voting down just because I didn't use/accept your answers

Comment: @DanielMorgan You was voted down because of you question, not because you didn't accept any answers!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not error when you call a function on a selector that did not return any DOM elements. It just silently eats the function. It is likely there is something wrong with your CSS selector, and no elements are being returns.

Do this:

```
console.log($(".twitter-timeline").contents().find(".timeline-header h1.summary"));
```

and see what you get in your console. This will tell you your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but it's been fixed now

Comment: I didn't use it, I removed the window in the code as suggested by someone else and it worked